# .NET CF parametrized tests

Tags: .net, compact-framework, nunit, smart-device

Is there possible to create parametrized tests (as in PHPUnit) in

Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.UnitTestFramework

or

NUnitLite

How can I better implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the latest [nunitlite](http://www.nunitlite.com/) libraries from [here](https://launchpad.net/nunitlite) and examined the code of the *netcf-2.0* and *netcf-3.5* assemblies using a decompiler.

From what I can see these assemblies contain several attributes suitable for parameterized unit testing, such as [[TestCase]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6.1), [[TestCaseSource]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.1), [[Range]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=range&r=2.6.1) and [[Random]](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=random&r=2.6.1).